# Secret Mission Axis and Allies

Tags: house-rules, axis-and-allies

My friend and I sat down one day and made up some "Secret Missions" for all of the countries in the board game Axis and Allies. For example, if Japan takes Western United States, they are immune from counter-attack for one turn. Also, if Russia takes Berlin within 3 turns, they receive an additional 15 IPC's from the bank.

There were 3 Secret Missions for each country, but I want to add more.

Do any of you have any more suggestions?

Please post them here as answers.

Here are the Secret Missions! Sorry it took so long!!!

**Russia (U.S.S.R.)**

-Take Berlin by Round 5 and gain 25 extra IPC's from the bank
-Take 3 German territories in ONE round and get 2 free tanks in any territory you control that has a factory (paying attention to the production limit)
-Take 3 Japanese territories and get 3 free infantry in ANY territory you own (not including the ones you took that turn)

**Germany**

-Take London by Round 2 and gain 1/2 of the air units you used in the attack (rounding down to the nearest whole number. Example: you send 5 planes, you get 2 extra)
-Control Algeria, Libya, Anglo-Egypt Sudan, Trans-Jordan, and Persia for ONE whole round and get 2 free tanks in Anglo-Egypt Sudan
-Take all of Africa by Round 3 and get a Battleship in the Mediterranean sea; take all of Africa by Round 4 and get a Cruiser in the Mediterranean

**United Kingdom**

-Destroy 3 Japanese boats and get 1 free Cruiser in a sea zone bordering one of your territories
-Destory all German boats (leaving none on the board) and get 3 free Fighters in the U.K.
-Take Western Europe by round 2 and all of the units left in W.E. gain a +1 to their defense for the first round of marriage

**Japan**

-Do the "Pearl Harbor" attack and lose no units and get 2 free Fighters in Japan
-Take China AND India by Round 3 and gain one free tank in any Japanese territory in Asia (excpet the ones just taken)
-Take the Western United States and become immune from counter-attack for one turn

**United States**

-Take both North African territories AND one European territory by Round 4 and get 2 free Artillery in any territory you own that is NOT in Europe (except ones you have just taken)
-Liberate an ally's capital and gain 10 IPC's from the bank
-Take one island every round for 3 consecutive rounds and gain one Transport and 2 Infantry in Hawaii (if you own it; if not, put it in the Western U.S.)

Comment: I think it would be better if you posted your list as part of your question.  That way answers can be judged for balance, theme and completeness.

Comment: Thank you Pat. I plan on adding the list here, I was just having trouble finding it. It will be posted within 24 hours

Comment: Giving bonuses to a player who completes a secret mission seems to be piling insult atop injury and guarantees the game to come to an even quicker conclusion. But the idea sure sounds fun. :-)

Comment: Do you actually take capitols so early :P?
Anyways, do you mean any particular A&A version?

Comment: The first round of marriage?

Answer (score 4):

#### Pacific Dominance

For each turn that Japan controls all of the Pacific islands at the end of a full turn they are rewarded with a free transport or submarine to be placed at a factory of their choice at the start of their turn. (This would require Japanese control of Hawaii, Midway, Australia, and New Zealand.)

#### Germans in the Atlantic

Similar to the **Sink the Convoys** variant proposed by GWLlosa, if Germany has one or more non-transport naval vessels in the Atlantic Ocean at the end of a full turn, the UK must roll the die and surrender that many IPCs.

Answer (score 2):

- **Germany holding all of Africa** at the end of a German turn. Perhaps with the reward of twice the IPC draw from African territories at the end of that turn.
- The axis getting the **US below 32 IPCs** at the end of a turn, which requires them to take Alaska, Hawaii, Brazil, or some other non-Chinese territory.
- Some sort of one-time IPC bonus for one or both axis powers if they meet up (i.e. **German and Japanese units in a single territory**)
- The ability to **produce units in a captured factory** on the first turn it was captured

Comment: I like the idea of awarding 5 IPCs to Germany and 5 to Japan the first time they "meet up." That was something they failed to do in the real war.

Answer (score 2):

**SINK THE CONVOYS**

At the end of the German turn, after the first full turn, if there are no transports in the Atlantic Ocean, Germany receives 2d6 IPCs from Britain (representing the economic damage).

Answer (score 1):

Interesting idea. Usually for those situations to occur something terribly wrong has happened to the opponent. ie. Japan being in Western USA

Granting even more bonus via IPCs would only widen that gap. So I would be extremely careful how you implement these "flavour" rules.

You might even consider the reverse and give a bonus to a player who took a bad beat. Not to reward poor strategy but to balance out the game if it is completely one sided.

ie. Britain gets 10 IPCs if there are no allied controlled territories in Africa.

Just a thought

Comment: Interesting idea. I would be concerned though that this would incentive someone to play to the weakness to get the bonus. For example, abandon Africa and play an Indian factory strategy knowing that the India strategy is a good one on its merits anyway, but now includes the added 10 IPC bonus for an African sacrifice they probably had to make anyway.

Comment: If Britain wants to give me Africa to make 10 IPCs I would gladly make that trade!

Comment: Capturing California would have been a HUGE moral victory for Japan, who should get the 10 IPCs for the round, whether or not America takes it back on its turn.

Answer (score 0):

One mission, secret or otherwise, that might have changed the course of the war (other than the atomic bomb), would be a German-Japanese link up in India, Persia, or somewhere in the Middle East.

It's not as far-fetched as it might have seemed. Japan's Admiral Yamamoto wanted to launch an amphibious invasion of India, until he changed plans and headed to Midway. Hitler originally decided to go after Russian oilfields in the Caucasus, then sent half the southern army to Stalingrad instead, capturing neither objective.

The Allies gave each other Lend Lease, the Axis, never, because they were separated. Germany was short of fuels, and Japan was short of  metals. A link up would have allowed trading. The result would have been worthy of a huge game bonus.

Also, understand the destruction they would have left in their wake. Japan would have occupied India, Germany would have grabbed the Suez Canal (if the linkup was with Rommel) or penetrated the Caucasus, and grabbed Russia's oilfields, (if it had been Paulus). Russia and China would have been inside a vast Axis ring, with Britain and the U.S. outside. The Axis might have gotten at least a negotiated peace and one-third of the world.

Answer (score 0):

**I think A&A generally needs more sea conditions**

Because sea warfare tends to end once a major fleet is destroyed. So how about this for *Revised and 1942 only!*:

**Axis: The unexpected Royal Navy's match**

If German total IPC worth of naval units is higher than that of the UK, Germany gets an extra 3IPCs per round.
*(meant to be an initial boost to german production and an incentive to buy some fleet)*

**Allies: La Resistance's desperation **

If no allied landings have taken place yet in europe, every round roll a dice ONCE at the end of Americans OR British  combat move phase. On a roll of 6, place an infantry unit in France, thus forcing a combat there or take the territory.
*Meant to be a counter to the previous and to have the allies consider delayed or no landings, instead bombing or supporting russi*